# How to generate access token for LinkedIn?

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I simple want to do "share with linkedIn" from my iOS application."

> How to generate access toke before sharing on linked In, how to
>   generate it ?

here is my code for posting in linked In. But its not working because I have not access token.

```
// For positing on linked In

    [[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] apiRequest:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json" method:@"POST" body:[bodyTxtView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"success called %@", response.data);
                }
              error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {
                   NSLog(@"error called %@", apiError.description);

                    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        LISDKAPIResponse *response = [apiError errorResponse];
                                                  NSString *errorText;
                              if (response)
                              {
                                    errorText = response.data;
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   errorText = apiError.description;
                                }
                        NSLog(@"error called %@", errorText);
                 });
          }];
```

Comment: visit  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676731/generating-linkedin-access-token

Answer (score 0):

Sample code is given in SDK (inside sample app) which was downloaded from https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads

Answer (score -1):

you  can use this class may be help you!!
  apikey = @"75pxdmwh5ghbil";
    secretkey = @"j3iYOXotT37VhPbM";

```
consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:apikey
                                    secret:secretkey
                                     realm:@"http://api.linkedin.com/"];

requestTokenURLString = @"https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken";
accessTokenURLString = @"https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken";
userLoginURLString = @"https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize";    
linkedInCallbackURL = @"hdlinked://linkedin/oauth";

requestTokenURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:requestTokenURLString] retain];
accessTokenURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:accessTokenURLString] retain];
userLoginURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:userLoginURLString] retain];
```