# LinkedIn Get Token Access via PHP cUrl Fail

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api, access-token

I try to create a register function with linkedIn in my website.

As you know, linkedIn has 2 step authentication to get Access token.

See StackOverflow answer here : [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676731/generating-linkedin-access-tokenhttp://)

From the thread above,
i try to do the second step with PHP cUrl.

```
$url = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" . $_GET['code'] . "&redirect_uri=A_URL&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SECRET";
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "POST",
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 1000,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
    "Content-Length: 1000" 
  )
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err      = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if (!$err) {
  $response = json_decode($response);
} else {
  throw new exception(__METHOD__ . '() ' . $err . ', on line : ' . __LINE__);
}
```

but when the curl_exec() is executed, the page goes to loading infinitely.

I do not know what's my mistake. I try to run the `$url` manually via the url box, it return a token and expired time successfully. So, i conclude the mistake is in the cUrl.

Any help guys ?,

Thank you very much.

Comment: Before you start do go any further read this:https://oauth.net/2/

Comment: That 2 step verification is called oauth,you are now making a client.

Comment: Here is Googles Play Ground for OAuth https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: You can test it out to see how OAuth works and when are tokens taken.And here is a simple kick start for you https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client

Comment: It's more complex than that one POST statement :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "GET"

and delete CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  option， It's useless.

Comment: I don't really understand what happen, but it works. ~

Comment: don't use CUSTOMREQUEST for GET and POST requests, use `CURLOPT_HTTPGET`  or `CURLOPT_POST`